# Licensing, updates for OpenJDK distribution from Fedora

Tags: java, fedora

What is the source for the OpenJDK RPMs found in Fedora distributions?

Is it safe to count on Fedora's RPMs for Java for commercial use with long term support?
Neither Oracle nor RedHat licensing seem to be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the source for the OpenJDK rpms found in Fedora distributions?

It's OpenJDK, which is supported.

> Is it safe to count on Fedora's rpms for Java for commercial use with long term support?

If you're using an LTS version, yes.

[OpenJDK Support from AdoptOpenJdk](https://adoptopenjdk.net/support.html)

[OpenJDK support form RedHat](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1299013)

Answer (score 0):

> What is the source for the OpenJDK RPMs found in Fedora distributions?

You can use Fedora's tools on Fedora to get the sources: `fedpkg clone java-11-openjdk; cd java-11-opendjk; fedpkg prep` and you should end up with a directory containing the entire set of (modified) sources for OpenJDK 11.

You can also grab a source rpm (`.src.rpm`) from an OpenJDK build in Fedora, such as https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=1350114. That source rpm contains an archive of the entire set of sources used in Fedora.

This script is actually used to generate the source archive: https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/java-11-openjdk/blob/master/f/generate_source_tarball.sh. If you take a look at it, you can see that it basically grabs sources from the OpenJDK 11 Updates Project itself: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk-updates/jdk11u/

> Is it safe to count on Fedora's RPMs for Java for commercial use with long term support? Neither Oracle nor RedHat licensing seem to be necessary.

There's a couple of parts to this answer:

- You can definitely use the Fedora packages for whatever task you want, including any commercial tasks. Fedora and OpenJDK are Free Software. They don't restrict your usage.
- You definitely don't need a license from Red Hat (or Oracle) to use OpenJDK and Fedora.
- If you want support, Fedora is probably the wrong place to look. Fedora is basically self-supported. Red Hat pays developers to work on OpenJDK try and fix issues as they come up. But there's no support or priority guarantees of any sort in Fedora (even if the same developers are active in both). If something breaks, you can only ask the community to help. Support (and priority in addressing bugs) is a major part of Red Hat's value proposition. That said, the developers who work on Fedora RPMs generally do a really good job.
- Fedora is definitely not a Long Term Supported release. Fedora releases go out of support (meaning no more security updates for OpenJDK, unless you upgrade to a newer version of Fedora) in a year or so. If you care about a stable (as in, unchanging base), Fedora is probably the wrong tool for the job. If you want to use Fedora, you will have to upgrade every year or so, or you will lose access to security updates in OpenJDK (among other components).

If you care about long term stability and don't want to go down a RHEL route, I would suggest looking at CentOS. It has some of the same downsides as Fedora (no real support, bugs may take some time to be resolved, security updates may not be as quick) but it is maintained by the community for a longer time.

If you just care about OpenJDK binaries on non-Fedora platforms I would also suggest looking at:

- OpenJDK binaries from the official OpenJDK 8 and 11 projects: https://adoptopenjdk.net/upstream.html
- AdoptOpenJDK binaries built by the community: https://adoptopenjdk.net/index.html

A number of other companies, groups and organizations provide OpenJDK builds that they maintain. I can't really speak about them.

(Disclaimer: I work at Red Hat. I used to work in the team that maintains OpenJDK for Fedora but I work in a different team now.)